# Counting functions and geodesic flows

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ and  $TN^{\perp}$ denote the normal bundle of a submanifold $N\subset M$. Now let's define $SN^{\perp}:=\{(x,v)\in TN^{\perp}: |v|=1\}, $ so this is a submanifold of $TM$ of dimension $n-1$. Let $\phi_t: TM\rightarrow TM$ denote the geodesic flow, and $\pi:TM\rightarrow M$.

Then in the book Geodesic flows the author introduces the function $A_N: SN^{\perp}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $A_N((x,v),t)\rightarrow |\det d_{(x,v)}(\pi\circ \phi_t)|_{T_{(x,v)}SN^{\perp}}|$.

Now I am not quite seeing why we are able to define this. To use the determinant we need that $ d_{(x,v)}(\pi\circ \phi_t)|_{T_{(x,v)}SN^{\perp}}$ maps to a subspace of dimension $n-1$ of $T_{x}M, $ but I can't see what this space actually is.  How does one check that this function is well-defined?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. What is $n$? What is $\phi$? What is $\pi$?

Comment: Sorry. I have edited@LeeMosher

Comment: What do you mean by $\det$ here? The determinant of a smooth map is not well defined without volume forms on the domain and codomain.

Comment: A few pages before the author mentions that the determiant of a linear map between finite dimensional hilbert spaces of the same dimension is always defined. Take an orthonormal basis of $X$ and consider the matrix $A_{ij}=\langle F(e_i), F(e_j)\rangle$, the determinant of $F$ is defined as $\sqrt{|A|}$. @Kajelad

Comment: @Lost I see. If that's the case, you need to specify a metric on $SN^\perp$. Are you using the one induced by the Sasaki metric on $TM$, or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using the metric induced by the Sasaki metric . @Kajelad

Comment: @Lost In that case, you can write $$|\det d(\pi\circ\phi_t)|=\sqrt{\frac{\det(\pi\circ\phi_t)^*g}{\det h}}$$ where $h$ is the induced metric on $SN^\perp$.